# How do I change the default Complete Action With?

Tags: settings

The handler select dialog mentions a setting in settings under `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications` but I can't find it.

Here's a list of actions for each app under Manage Applications:

- Force Stop
- Uninstall
- Clear Data
- Move to SD card/phone
- Clear Cache
- Clear Defaults

And this is the application info for Firefox, which I know for certain is a Complete Action With app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The one you want is 'Clear Defaults' - once clicked, the 'Handler Select' dialog will pop up next time you invoke that particular action.

Comment: Thank you... I don't know how I missed that, must have been lumping it with "clear data" and "clear cache".

Answer (score 7):

I believe they are talking about the "Clear Defaults" option.  I'm not a dev but I believe that when you install Firefox the default Complete Action for all the "Browser" related actions and intents is cleared and so when a user clicks on a link or a bookmark, they are given the "Complete Action with..." dialog.  From there they can choose Firefox as the default.  Once this is done, in order to undo it, you'd choose the "Clear Defaults" option.

To the best of my knowledge this is all that is available from a "user" standpoint, anything beyond that is in the "development" territory which is off-topic here and better suited for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).