# how can I change defaults in Android?

Tags: default-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default Complete Action With?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/how-do-i-change-the-default-complete-action-with)

I've accumulated a number of programs that do the same thing (browsers, mp3 players, video players etc), and some of are set as defaults.

How can I change the defaults?  For instance, let's say I'm tired of Opera and want to to switch back to the stock browser, but I want to leave Opera installed, how can I do that?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S with Froyo.

Answer (score 5):

Find the application which currently handles the action by default in your application list (Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage Applications).  Once you've found the app in question (note that the 'Manage Applications' list is almost, but not quite, in alphabetical order), tap it, and then tap the 'Clear defaults' button.

Then, next time you start an action that would previously have been handled by the app, you'll get the 'Which app should I use' popup.